# user role editor - restoring admin capabilities

Tags: wordpress, roles

Can anyone help me with a problem I'm having after using the User Role Editor plugin on my wordpress site.  It's restricted my admin account so I am locked out of any theme/user/appearance/plugins areas of the dashboard. 
The plugin support suggested deleting the plugin via FTP, which I have done, but it's made no difference.  I tried reinstalling the plugin and editing the role again, but am unable to find options to restore the super admin capabilities.
Does anyone have any ideas on how restore the super-admin capabilities to my admin login?
many thanks,
Louise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm wondering how that happened?...oh well.

first thought would be do a local install of wp (your exact version). assuming you have phpmyadmin access, go to `wp_options` table and search `wp_user_roles` in `options_name` field. it will be something like:

`a:9:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:140:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";b:1;s:10:"edit_files";b:1;s:14:"manage_options";b:1;s:17:`

Note i did not paste it all, it is really long.

Now replace `wp_user_roles` field in broken db (remembering to backup broken `wp_user_roles` field first) with what you get from fresh install db's `wp_user_roles` field.

BEWARE: you'll lose all user info, but if you backed like suggested, you can rebuild it. we have the technology

Good Luck